# TypeError: sing() missing 1 required positional argument: 'end'

Tags: python

once again, I'm struggling with a bit of my code, ive got an error : **TypeError: sing() missing 1 required positional argument: 'end'**

As I'm new to all this coding and I'm still trying to work out how to do everything, I'm a bit confused on how to solve it. I'd ask my teacher, however we're not seeing him until Monday, and that's when the code is due to be finished.

```
#this program is going to be playing the 99 bottles of (something) on the wall
    #it will give you a choice on what you can have inside the bottle
    #e.g soda, coke, lemonade, beer, wine, ect
user_input = input("What would you like inside your bottle?")
print(user_input)
def sing(b, end):
    print(b or 'No more','bottle'+('s' if b-1 else ''), end)
for i in range(99, 0, -1):
    sing(str(i) + 'of' + user_input + 'on the wall,')
    sing(str(i) + ', of'+ user_input +',')
    print('Take one down, pass it around,')
    sing(str(i-1), 'of' + user_input + 'on the wall.\n'))
```

Comment: I think you have one extra `)` in the last line

Comment: Note how in the first two invocations you are only passing a single string to `sing`. Maybe those should also be `sing(str(i), "of...")`?